# Spring data supports being unique for a single value?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a requirement for my database design. I have a boolean column on my DB and I need to make only one value `true` in the table, the rest of them should be false. If 0 or 2 values have been tried to update as true then db should throw constraint violation.

```
@Table(
        name = "config",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"isActive"}, name = "isActive_uniqueness"))
public class Config {
// ...
// ...

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: In general, either function-based index: `unique index on config(nullif(is_active,false))` or  partial index: `unique index on config(is_active) where is_active = true` may help (unique constraints do not support expressions). 
Declaring that in JPA could be tricky, try smth. like: `indexes = @Index(name = "xxx", columnList = "nullif(is_active,false)", unique = true)` or  `indexes = @Index(name = "xxx", columnList = "nullif(isActive,false)", unique = true)`